# using DoH/DoT with your ISP?

Tags: dns, doh, dot

Is there a point to using DoT or DoH while your DNS is your ISP from a security (not privacy) standpoint?

Assuming I trust my home network, could there be something along the way between my ISP and me that MitM (or some other attack?) me?

If this is possible, is there a record of such an attack taking place?